# MATLAB: How to slide a window over a matrix without padding?

Tags: matlab, window

I'll illustrate my problem on an example

I have a 3x100 matrix and I want to slide a 3x3 filter over it.
However, I do not want any of the padding that imfilter would use, such as X, symmetric, replicate, etc., which would yield a 3x100 output.
I rather want the sliding window to be only applied when there is real data, such that my output would be 1x (100 - 4).

What would be the most elegant (loopless) way to do this in matlab?

Comment: Are you using the `'conv'` option (or any others) with `imfilter`? And you can't just use `C = imfilter(A,B);` `C = C(2,2:end-1);`? For such small sizes, that's likely to be very efficient.

Comment: I think that you mean that your output would be 1 x 98 rather than 1 x 96

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`conv2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html) function with 'Valid' as the shape parameter which will only provide results when there is a complete overlap between the filter and the data.

```
filtered = conv2(data, filter, 'valid');
```

Comment: FYI, `imfilter` uses [correlation rather than convolution](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/12684/difference-between-correlation-and-convolution-on-an-image) by default, hence my question in the comments above.